# ng-class not working on table?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have the following html code:

```
<table class="comp-table comp-table__col-{{tableColumns}}" 
  ng-class="{'comp-table-consultant__col-{{configuratorColumns}}':  returnTrue() }">
   some table html markup in here
</table>
```

And the function in my controller:

```
  $scope.returnTrue = function () {
    return true;
  };
```

However it doesn't apply my ng-class to the table, what am I missing here? Is ng-class incompatible with tables?

The class names are correct and also the expression are evaluated correctly (already checked that).

Comment: Tested and worked fine. Can you replicate it in a plunker?

Comment: AngularJS version? Can you show what the rendered HTML for the table's class and ng-class looks like?

Comment: @tasseKATT are you sure `{{tableColumns}}` interpolated content will be evaluated in `ng-class` class name? I doubt about that.

Comment: Yes it will: http://plnkr.co/edit/U5uAgNYovNhavrwWMFDX?p=preview

Comment: @tasseKATT that's pretty much. Thanks :) and seems to be fine till `1.2.0`

Comment: @tasseKATT yes it does https://jsfiddle.net/r6cd2pwh/ seems to be a different issue.

Comment: @tasseKATT Using Angularjs 1.4.8. The rendered HTML looks fine apart from that class. If I added manually as a class it also works. Can it be a issue that I am using nested controllers and that this table is actually inside a loop? Unfortunately can't show you the rendered html.

Comment: Yes, you probably have a scope issue. Try using objects intead, for example "{{viewModel.tableColumns}}" and see if that works better.

Answer (score 0):

seems if you switch class with ng-class it works. The following solution worked in the end:

```
<table ng-class="{'comp-table-consultant__col-{{configuratorColumns}}':  returnTrue() }"
  class="comp-table comp-table__col-{{tableColumns}}">
   some table html markup in here
</table>
```